# Sitecore Lucene Search "Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode" Error

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore-mvc

I am using sitecore8. indexes in sitecore is working fine. i am getting a "**Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode**." Error in my code file  when the debugger hits the code **using (var context=searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())**  line of code. I am using Lucene.Net version 3.0.3.0

```
var searchIndex = Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.GetIndex(SearchIndexName);
using (var context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
}
```

STACK TRACE :

```
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(TimeoutTracker timeout)
at Sitecore.Search.Index.Sitecore.Search.IIndexMutex.EnterOpearionContext()
at Sitecore.Search.IndexContextBase.EnterOperationContext(ILuceneIndex index)
at Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext..ctor(ILuceneIndex index)
at Sitecore.Search.Index.CreateSearchContext()
at MyProject.Common.NewSearchManager.Search(String searchString, String ProgramCampusStage, ScoreDoc[]& hitScores) in e:\Source Control\GIT\MyProject-sitecore-mvc\Code\Dependencies\MyProject\Common\NewSearchManager.cs:line 148
at MyProject.Repositories.SearchRepository.Search(String searchTxt, String ProgramCampusStage, String searchCategory, String& message, Int32 offset, Int32 limit, String hostName, String searchIndexName, String currentDatabase, String searchCampus) in e:\Source Control\GIT\MyProject-sitecore-mvc\Code\Dependencies\MyProject\Repositories\SearchRepository.cs:line 36
at MyProject.Controllers.SearchController.GetSearchResult(String userid, String searchTxt, String searchCategory, String offset, String limit, String hostName, String searchCampus) in e:\Source Control\GIT\MyProject-sitecore-mvc\Code\Dependencies\MyProject\Controllers\SearchController.cs:line 267
```

Comment: can you add entire stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace as follows :

Comment: can you try to update all your indexes?

Comment: do you use multiple searches, 2nd before closing the first `using`?

Comment: not using multiple search . on making mutiple request to the above code i get this error. some time it working fine some time it does not. because of the error

Comment: @SitecoreClimber. I have updated my indexes .even then i get this error. Some times it works with out a problem and i am able to retrieve the the search result .On multiple calls it causes this issue.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169583/sitecore-error-rebuilding-quick-search-index-after-wffm-2-4-install-attempt - restarting IIS is a potential fix.

Comment: @RichardSeal restarted the iis and also deployed it to qa server . it still causes the same issue . Issue happens in local server as well as same issue in QA server.

Comment: Do you embed somehow the SearchContext ? having multiple search contexts at the same time ? 
As far as I know, Lucene can open multiple indexes for read, but only one for writing.  So there is no reason if you are not updating any indexes that you can perform read actions. So the problem relays in the interface of sitecore to lucene...